# Mysql query showing only lowest price of certain values does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the cheapest rooms per city and only show them after I run the query. If the price of the rooms are equal, then show both. I tried group by on city or price, but that did not work unfortunately.

What I currently have:

```
booking:

| type       | pID        |city           |price    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|----------
| B          |  COD12      |    Canvas    |  240    |
| B          |  COD40      |    Canvas    |  200    |
| B          |  KHOD20     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
| B          |  KHOD60     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
| B          |  BHOD60     |    Bordeaux  |  120    |
| B          |  BHOD80     |    Bordeaux  |  160    |
```

What I want:

```
| type        | pID        |city          |price    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|----------
| B          |  COD40      |    Canvas    |  200    |
| B          |  KHOD20     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
| B          |  KHOD60     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
| B          |  BHOD60     |    Bordeaux  |  120    |
```

Query I tried:

```
select type,pID,city,price
  from booking
 where (city, price) 
    in (select city, min(price) 
          from booking
         group by 1)
```

What it shows after the query(Bordeaux doesn't show the cheapest price):

```
| type        | pID        |city          |price    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|----------
| B          |  COD40      |    Canvas    |  200    |
| B          |  KHOD20     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
| B          |  KHOD60     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
| B          |  BHOD80     |    Bordeaux  |  160    |
```

Comment: your query already gives correct results : [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=032e48320f3be9a1217a58308a7ddf24)

Comment: Hmm thats weird in MySQL, where my database is almost the same, shows something different

Comment: What do you get if you use `Group By city` in the subquery, instead of `Group By 1` ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I get the same incorrect result. It is weird because it only happens with Bordeaux